# twitter4j : Update filter of a running Stream

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am running a stream using twitter4j with a filter as follows -

```
    FilterQuery filter = new FilterQuery();
    filter.follow(userIds);
    twitterStream.filter(filter);
```

I need to update the filters like add new people to follow as follows - 
userIds.add(NEW_ID)

Can i do this without intercepting the flow or without halting and starting the existing twitterStream ?

Comment: No, you've to rerun the program if you want to update.

Comment: What if i start another stream ?

Comment: You can run only one streaming connection at a time per IP address. If you start another stream, your old stream will be disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add more followers, but you could start another stream with different credentials

Comment: can you explain with the help of an example.